# How to restore checkpoint file into tf.learn.Estimator for text classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow ,Now i am working on text classification ,i took a code from tensorflow github pag, I successfully trained my model and stored the checkpoint and meta file, but i don't know how to restore the model file and query on it, i googled about this problem but i can't find out the solution for this problem, most of the solutions are based on restoring the tensorflow variable. so please help me to solve this problem.
The code is from here,
[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification_cnn.py][1]

```
classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model,model_dir = "/home/local/models/")
```

I am using tf.contrib.learn to create classifier by loading the cnn_model function and fit training data into it ,but i don't know how to restore the model file, and query on it.